# Linq queries are very slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table that contains a list of builds. What I am trying to achieve is to group those builds by reference ID and take 5 or 10 latest (by `build_date`) and see check their statuses. So I am currently doing the group by and returning them.

```
using (var ctx = new Entities())
{
    return ctx.Builds.Where(x => x.build_date > dateTime)
                .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    x.configuration_id
                })
                .Select(s => new ConfigurationBuilds
                {
                    ConfId = s.Key.configuration_id,
                    Builds = s.Select(x => x).OrderByDescending(d => d.build_date).Take(count)
                })
                .ToList();
}
```

Later on in another method I will check all the statuses `Builds` items to see if they match any criteria, something like:

```
items.Where(build => build.Builds.Count() >= 9)
                    .Where(build => build.Builds.All(x => !x.build_status.Equals("SUCCESSFUL")))
                    .ToList();
```

The problem is with the first query where I do `groupBy`. That one is extremelly slow, how could I optimize that routine?

I createad a dummy routine to select all builds and group by statuses

```
var items = ctx.Builds.Where(x => x.build_date > dateTime).OrderByDescending(x=>x.build_id)
                    .GroupBy(x => new {
                        confID = x.configuration_id,
                        status = x.build_status
                        })
                .Select(s => new 
                    {
                        Id = s.Key.confID,
                        Status = s.Key.status,
                        Cnt = s.Count()
                    }).OrderBy(d=>d.Id)
                    .ToList();
```

This one on same data is blazing fast, but does not really do what I need. I need to: For each configuration group select n number of latest builds that match some criteria. How to do that?

Comment: @TimSchmelter there is a Non-Unique Non-Clustered index and I am using SQL Server v12

Comment: It looks like you're using Linq to Entities or Entity Framework.  The thing to remember about these queries is that they get translated into SQL.  Using SQL Profiler, you can capture the query actually generated and executed.  Then you can figure out how what indexes you need to add to improve its performance.

Answer (score 2):

A good way way is to determine what SQL it's generating is to use a tool like [LINQpad](http://www.linqpad.net).  Once you get an idea of what the SQL looks like, you can use SQL tools like execution plan generation.

Or you can use SQL profiler to see what's going on with the SQL queries too.

Comment: Thaks for that, I was just wondering if there is something obviously wrong with my code.

Comment: How you select the builds collection in the select parameter might not perform well.  But using profiler tools is the best bet to identifying he problem.